# Not able to set a Measure to Text Box in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My Measure is :

```
Last7days = 
CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('application_overview'[posting_number]),
        FILTER(ALL('application_overview'), 'application_overview'[app_submitted_date] >= TODAY()-700)
)
```

I am getting the result if I set it to a card, And also able to set some other Measures to the title of a Text box. What is the issue with this Measure, like for what reason I am not able to set it to a Text box?

Comment: afaik you cannot use measures inside a textbox, not in the title, not in the body. It can just be used for some static text. (just to be sure, are you talking about the textbox created through the "insert" menu?)

Comment: yes, just resolved it .Its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate a string to the result, Then you will be able to set it to the Text box.
e.g:

```
Last7daysPostings = 
var res = CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('application_overview'[posting_id]),
        FILTER(ALL('application_overview'), 'application_overview'[app_submitted_date] >= TODAY()-7)
        )
return res&""
```

Comment: Can you complete your answer please ? How can we display the content of the variable res in a text box please ?

Comment: concatenate the output stored the in the variable with a blank string as I have done and return that.